# six-dot icon on home screen shows app icons, not app names

Tags: launcher, app-icons

Something on my phone changed.  I don't know what or how, but now when I press the 6-dot icon in the middle of the bottom row of my home screen, I get pages of app icons without any names.  How can I get the names back?

Comment: Is it possible that you have somehow installed or activated an alternate launcher?

Comment: Somewhere I very recently read that a Cyanogen update might cause problems like this,

Comment: Your phone is on Cyanogen? You should specify that on your question because it is pretty relevant.